# Text alignment center - shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I'm creating a simple console based script using shell script.It will be run on my bash shell
Its a simple menu based driven display some set of options.

Now I want to do center align the text depending on the screen size.
How do I align the text at center of the screen?Please assis me

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:)

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols) 
title="Hello world!" 
printf "%*s\n" $(((${#title}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$title"
```

Comment: if you need a one-liner, that takes input from command-line arguments:

```printf "%*s\n" $(( ( $(echo $* | wc -c ) + 80 ) / 2 )) "$*"```

takes in input from the command line arguments, uses wc to count the number of characters, and default justifies to 80 characters.

Comment: Adding the length of the title shifts it to the right by its length, just ``$COLUMNS/2`` works great for me.

Answer (score 13):

On BSD-based systems, including MacOS, the `fmt` utility has a `-c` flag to center text.

```
echo $text | fmt -c -w $COLUMNS
```

Unfortunately, GNU `fmt` has an incompatible -c flag and no alternative for centering.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '$sp = " " x (($ENV{COLUMNS} - length) / 2); s/^/$sp/'
```

Comment: Try it to see. Just add the line into your script, piping the text to be centered to it (`generate-text | perl ...`) or using it as an argument (`perl ... text.txt`)

Comment: Finally I found the solution:
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
title="Hello world!"
printf "%*s\n" $(((${#title}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$title"

Comment: @KarthickV: please post your solution as a separate answer, not as a comment to this answer. It will help others find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

To print text at center :

```
echo "Some Text" | sed  -e :a -e "s/^.\{1,$(tput cols)\}$/ & /;ta" | tr -d '\n' | head -c $(tput cols)
```

Output:

```
                                    Some Text
```