# how to center script output in the middle of the screen?

Tags: bash

Here i have a binary clock which outputs binary clock in 16 different colors and i am trying to make it appear in center of the screen but cant do it. If you have any suggestions how to do it then please let me know.
thanks

```
color=("0;30" "0;31" "0;32" "0;33" "0;34" "0;35" "0;36" "0;37" "1;30" "1;31" "1;32" "1;33" "1;34" "1;35" "1;36" "1;37")
color2=${#color[*]}
while true;
do
clear
echo -ne '\e['${color[$((RANDOM%color2))]}m
hour=$(date +%H)
minute=$(date +%M)
second=$(date +%S)
hour_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$hour" | bc)
minute_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$minute" | bc)
second_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$second" | bc)
printf "%06d\n" "$hour_binary"
printf "%06d\n" "$minute_binary"
printf "%06d" "$second_binary"
sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Do you mean the center of your terminal window? What do you mean by screen?

Comment: yes in the center of terminal window

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text alignment center - shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471951/text-alignment-center-shell-script)

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the center of the terminal window, get the columns and rows of the terminal window with:

```
COLS=$(tput cols)
ROWS=$(tput lines)
CLOCKWIDTH=8       # Assuming a HH:MM:SS format
CENTERCOL=$((COLS/2))
CENTERCOL=$((CENTERCOL-CLOCKWIDTH))
CENTERROW=$((ROWS/2))
```

And then use the tput command to set the cursor position with:

```
tput cup $CENTERCOL $CENTERROW
```

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/spice-up-your-unix-linux-shell-scripts.html for an example using tput and https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html for more information about the tput command.

Comment: Backticks are a bit depreciated in 2014. Think using `$( )` form instead, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 2):

What I would do :

```
cols=$(tput cols)
lines=$(tput lines)
numcols=$(((cols-6)/2))
numlines=$((lines/2))

while true; do
    clear
    tput setaf $((RANDOM%8))
    hour=$(date +%H)
    minute=$(date +%M)
    second=$(date +%S)
    hour_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$hour" | bc)
    minute_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$minute" | bc)
    second_binary=$(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$second" | bc)
    tput cup $numlines $numcols
    printf "%06d\n" "$hour_binary"
    tput cup $((numlines+1)) $numcols
    printf "%06d\n" "$minute_binary"
    tput cup $((numlines+2)) $numcols
    printf "%06d" "$second_binary"
    tput cup $((numlines+3)) $numcols
    sleep 1
done
```

I have replaced hard coded ansi sequences by using tput for the colors too

Comment: after i added a title the clock wont line up in middle. the title is bit to the left. How can i make them all centralized  like in the Microsoft word where you can center the title.

Comment: Maybe by understanding what's going on and reading documentation ?